# How come <T extends Comparable<T>> working as <T extends Comparable<? super T>>?

Tags: java

suppose we have

```
class Fruit implements Comparable<Fruit>
{
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Fruit o) { return 0; }
}

class Apple extends Fruit{}

class Main
{

    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        function(new Apple()); // this shouldn't work because Apple is implementing Comparable<Fruit>, not Comparable<Apple>
    }

    public static<T extends Comparable<T>> void function(T t){}
}
```

Code is working without any issue.

My question is why `<T extends Comparable<T>>` working like `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`. whats the difference ?

Thanks.

[Edited] -  A passage from book
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFUbH.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between <? super T> and <? extends T> in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java)

Comment: No both scenarios are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You compile with Java 8 I think. 
Because, before Java 8, you should not pass the compilation and have this error :

> Bound mismatch: The generic method function(T) of type Main is not
>   applicable for the arguments (Apple). The inferred type Apple is not a
>   valid substitute for the bounded parameter >

I think what you read in your book refers to generic use before Java 8.
But i didn't know that Java 8 had less constraint on this kind of case. 
Is it a side-effect of the large use of inference in Java 8 that Java 8 calls the "improved inference" ?

Comment: yes i was using java8. Just Compiled with jdk 1.6 and got compilatation error, while java8 compiles smoothly.

Comment: It kinda seems to be java 8 bug because if we change function defination to

Comment: `private static<T extends Comparable<T>> void function(List<T> t){}`

Comment: and then call it like

Comment: `function(new ArrayList<Apple>());`

Comment: Java 8 also gives compilation error, which seems right.
Thanks for clearing. @davidxxx

Comment: Just for your information, book is written for java 8. Core Java Volume 1 - Fundamentals 10th edition by Cay S. Horstmann

Answer (score 0):

In this case it is beacuse class `Fruit` is a superclass of itself

The difference is here

`<T extends Comparable<T>>` accepts Comparable with arguement of `type T`
`<T extends Comparable<? super T>>` accepts Comparable with arguements of `type T and its super classes`. Here Since in java every class is a superclass of itself, `Fruit is also a superclass of Fruit` .Thats why you see like they are working the same way
But if you used class `Apple` as `T` you will see the difference.

Comment: if this is the case then this should also work but it isn't.

call : `function(new ArrayList<Apple>());` ---

protoype : `private static<T extends Comparable<T>> void function(List<T> t){}`

it requires `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>` as it should be.

Comment: @Ibrahim In your case ,  the comment // this shouldn't work because Apple is implementing Comparable<Fruit>, not Comparable<Apple> is not right. in this case Apple in implementing Comparable<Apple> Because you are passing type Apple to function

Comment: Okay but we know that Apple is a subclass of Fruit So whether it implements comparable<Fruit>  even Apple will fit there beacause apple IS A FRUIT

Comment: no in generics List<Apple> is not a subclass of List<Fruit>.

Comment: `f=a; // Error : Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Apple> to List<Fruit>`

Comment: Thanks..Thats where super comes in

Comment: yea exactly, but why java going against book. don't know.

Comment: Yeah i think its java version issue. as well now